# How to decide if an Ext.js App is using Classic or Modern theme toolkit?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-touch

If I have only the app.js file of an pre-existing Ext.js application, How do I find out if it is using the modern theme or the classic theme ?

Comment: The actual application in question is this: [CMDBUILD READY2USE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmdbuild/files/ready2use-2.1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t, you will need the App.json file in order to get all this information, in the application in question, look for the ready2use.json file, Its a classic app using triton, an excerpt:

```
"id":"0332b510-f907-44a9-97c6-3af68e752bfd",
"toolkit":"classic",
"theme":"theme-triton",
"hash":"b201882bf4eb6467ffa98522c701a54f43b053d2",
"profile":"openmaint",
"resources":{
   "path":"openmaint/resources",
   "shared":"resources"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use Browser console to find toolkit

```
Ext.toolkit
```

Which will show you current toolkit application is using
[image]